# IBM Cloud: How to access the API for billing and usage?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, billing

How can I retrieve usage and cost data for my IBM Cloud account using a REST API? I found that there are [billing related commands and I can export some data as JSON](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/cloud-usage.html#reviewing-ibm-cloud-services-resources-and-usage). Is there an API or SDK I can use, ideally Python?

Here are some of the [IBM Cloud billing commands](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud/cli_billing.html#ibmcloud_billing) I use:

```
ibmcloud billing resource-instances-usage --json

ibmcloud billing  account-usage --json
```

Are there equivalent APIs for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED:**
An API is now documented here: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/metering-reporting

---

**OLD:**

I couldn't find a documented API but used the tracing to see how the above commands are executed. Using a valid access_token a program can call the metering host and obtain usage data for an account, resource group or all resource instances:

A GET on the following URL with an account ID and month as YYYY-MM returns a JSON object with all resource usage and related cost:

```
https://metering-reporting.ng.bluemix.net/v4/accounts/account_id/resource_instances/usage/?_limit=100&_names=true
```

I coded up a small [Python script that dumps that data or prints it as CSV](https://github.com/data-henrik/pyBill/).

```
def processResourceInstanceUsage(account_id, billMonth):
    METERING_HOST="https://metering-reporting.ng.bluemix.net"
    USAGE_URL="/v4/accounts/"+account_id+"/resource_instances/usage/"+billMonth+"?_limit=100&_names=true"

    url=METERING_HOST+USAGE_URL
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "{}".format(iam_token),
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    response=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print ("\n\nResource instance usage for first 100 items")
    return response.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub repo [openwhisk-cloud-usage-samples](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/openwhisk-cloud-usage-sample) uses a serverless approach to getting data via APIs. Examples are included in the repo. It's written in Javascript, but a package it uses [openwhisk-jsonetl](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/openwhisk-jsonetl) was designed so that you could declare the URLs and parameters in YAML (rather than writing code) to request and transform JSON.