# Is there a way to get consolidated IBM Cloud billing in one api call

Tags: ibm-cloud, billing

I need to get a consolidated bill based on organizations or resource groups. Something like:

```
    org1   $100
    org2   $200
    rg1    $150
```

Is there a way I can get this in one api call? I can get a detailed bill using following cli command:

```
ibmcloud billing account-usage
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333121/ibm-cloud-how-to-access-the-api-for-billing-and-usage

Comment: @VidyasagarMachupalli - That is a very old question, things have changed a lot since then.

Comment: I recommend this tutorial to get an overview: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/cloud-usage.html It does not provide a single command. Are you looking for an API or a command?

Comment: @data_henrik - preferably an api call so I can send a consolidated bill as an email.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single API call which gives usage per org. But there is API call `ibmcloud billing org-usage $org` which retrieves usage for a single ORG. You can write a small shell script to call the API in a loop over a list of org.

```
#!/bin/bash
ibmcloud login --apikey @ibmcloud_key
ibmcloud target  -o ORGNAME1 -s SPACENAME 
org_list=(ORGNAME1 ORGNAME2)
echo "Get usage for each org...." 
for org in "$org_list[@]"
do
    ibmcloud billing org-usage $org >> billing.txt
done
```

Comment: I am unable to call this script from a function.

Comment: What programming language are you using to create your function? The above script is a bash script. You can refactor that into a function if you need to.

Comment: I am using python, but where will billing.txt be saved? When you run it as a function on bluemix?

Answer (score 1):

The answers by @VidyasagarMachupalli and @data_henrik are appropriate. While there is no single API call, the `ibmcloud billing resource-instances-usage` provides the closest solution as it segments data based on org, space, and resource group.

You can use a spreadsheet (i.e. pivot table) to take the last step and sum the data for an entire org or resource group. The tutorial mentioned - [this section](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/cloud-usage.html#explore-usage-with-the-command-line) - does exactly this approach using the IBM Cloud CLI, jq, and json2csv.

```
ibmcloud billing resource-instances-usage --output json | jq '.[] | {month,resource_name,resource_group_name,organization_name,space_name,metric: .usage[].metric,cost : .usage[].cost}' | json2csv -f month,resource_name,resource_group_name,organization_name,space_name,metric,cost -p

┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ "month"       │ "resource_name"              │ "resource_group_name"                    │ "organization_name"                  │ "space_name"           │ "metric"       │ "cost"        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│               │                              │                                          │                                      │                        │ "AUTHORIZED_US │               │
│ "2018-11"     │ "Continuous Delivery"        │ "default"                                │ ""                                   │ ""                     │ ERS_PER_MONTH" │ 0             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│               │                              │                                          │                                      │                        │ "AUTHORIZED_US │               │
│ "2018-11"     │ "Continuous Delivery"        │ "default"                                │ ""                                   │ ""                     │ ERS_PER_MONTH" │ 0             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│               │                              │                                          │                                      │                        │ "JOB_EXECUTION │               │
│ "2018-11"     │ "Continuous Delivery"        │ "default"                                │ ""                                   │ ""                     │ S_PER_MONTH"   │ 0             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│               │                              │                                          │                                      │                        │ "JOB_EXECUTION │               │
│ "2018-11"     │ "Continuous Delivery"        │ "default"                                │ ""                                   │ ""                     │ S_PER_MONTH"   │ 0             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│               │                              │                                          │                                      │                        │ "DEVOPS_INSIGH │               │
│ "2018-11"     │ "DevOps Insights"            │ "default"                                │ ""                                   │ ""                     │ TS_ITEMS"      │ 0             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│               │                              │                                          │                                      │                        │ "instance_hour │               │
│ "2018-11"     │ "Kubernetes Service"         │ "default"                                │ ""                                   │ ""                     │ s"             │ 0             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│               │                              │                                          │                                      │                        │ "DATA_POINTS_P │               │
│ "2018-11"     │ "Monitoring"                 │ ""                                       │ "van_org"                            │ "dev"                  │ ER_MONTH"      │ 0             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│               │ "IBM Bluemix Platform Runtim │                                          │                                      │                        │ "GB_HOURS_PER_ │               │
│ "2018-11"     │ e"                           │ ""                                       │ "van_org"                            │ "dev"                  │ MONTH"         │ 0.00035       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│               │                              │                                          │                                      │                        │ "GB_HOURS_PER_ │ 3.51056366597 │
│ "2018-11"     │ "IBM Bluemix Node.js"        │ ""                                       │ "van_org"                            │ "dev"                  │ MONTH"         │ 2222          │
```

Comment: I tried this but this is not the solution I can use inside a function or lambda to run. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The CLI communicates with an API; you'd mimic the same approach in a Function. Set the IBMCLOUD_TRACE=true env var and run the command, you'll then see the RESTful call that the CLI is doing. The [Cloud Usage sample application](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/openwhisk-cloud-usage-sample) referenced from the tutorial uses Cloud Functions to retrieve billing data.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Cloud offers APIs for [usage metering](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/usage-metering) and [usage reports](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/metering-reporting). The integrated [API overview page in the IBM Cloud docs](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/) lists them under Platform Services.

I also recommend this [IBM Cloud solution tutorial on reviewing cloud usage](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/cloud-usage.html) for an introduction. I just checked and it does not yet have the new APIs, but it's worth reading nonetheless.