# Trying to run code in IBM Cloud Functions

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I have following code I am trying to run in IBM function to get billing data out:

```
iam_token = 'Bearer eyJraWQiOiIyMDE3MTAzMC0wM****'
def processResourceInstanceUsage(account_id, billMonth):
    METERING_HOST = "https://metering-reporting.ng.bluemix.net"
    USAGE_URL = "/v4/accounts/"+account_id + \
        "/resource_instances/usage/"+billMonth+"?_limit=100&_names=true"

    url = METERING_HOST+USAGE_URL
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "{}".format(iam_token),
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print("\n\nResource instance usage for first 100 items")
    return response.json()

processResourceInstanceUsage('*****', '11')
```

For some reason, I keep on getting 201 unauthorized error. I tried creating iam_token many times. It still gives the same error.

Comment: Does your code work when run standalone? How do you create the action, how do you invoke it? Please add details

Comment: Are you getting a 201 response or an unauthorized error? That status code doesn't usually got with that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things that should be taken care in the code you provided.

- The month you are passing is wrong. It should be in **YYYY-MM** format.
- **account_id** should be the id next to your **Account** name when you run `ibmcloud target`
- For IAM token, run this command `ibmcloud iam oauth_tokens`. If you want to generate *access token* using your Platform API Key, refer to this [link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/apikey_iamtoken.html). The word **Bearer** is not required as this is not an authorization token.

Once you have all this in place, create an IBM Cloud function (Python 3), add the below code, pass the account_id and token and invoke the action to see the result . IBM Cloud function expects a dictionary as an input/parameter and JSON as response

```
import sys
import requests

def main(dict):
    METERING_HOST="https://metering-reporting.ng.bluemix.net"
    account_id="3d40d89730XXXXXXX"
    billMonth="2018-10"
    iam_token="<IAM_TOKEN> or <ACCESS_TOKEN>"
    USAGE_URL="/v4/accounts/"+account_id+"/resource_instances/usage/"+billMonth+"?_limit=100&_names=true"

    url=METERING_HOST+USAGE_URL
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "{}".format(iam_token),
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    response=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print ("\n\nResource instance usage for first 100 items")
    return { 'message': response.json() }
```

This worked for me and returned a JSON with region-wise billing data.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52333233/1432067